# Dans une lettre de motivation: comment dire « Je suis quelqu’un qui… » plus professionnellement?

Tags: vocabulaire, formulation-idiomatique, registre

Je voulais dire que *« Je suis quelqu’un qui aime bien expérimenter avec les nouvelles technologies »* mais je pensais que la phrase trop formelle. Il y a une autre manière à le dire ?

Comment: The following suggestion wouldn’t work so well (or even be necessary) in your example (where you’re talking about something that is definite/objective, such as your love//like//passion for experimenting w/new technologies), but in contexts where the description/quality is more subjective/opinion-based, perhaps you could replace the slightly presumptuous “**Je suis** quelqu’un qui [travaille bien en équipe] (for example)” with “**Je me vois//perçois comme** quelqu’un//une personne qui [travaille bien en équipe].”(when someone tells me unequivocally that s/he is 'such & such,' I see red flags)

Comment: Personnellement, je trouve que "J'aime bien" n'est pas assez positif. On dirait que c'est quelque chose de quelconque, qui est un peu au dessus du reste, mais sans plus, ou alors que vous n'assumez pas. Pour vendre ce genre de chose, il faut dire "J'aime expérimenter ..." !

Answer (score 7):

> Je me passionne pour les nouvelles technologies.
>   Je suis passionné par les nouvelles technologies.

Je me passionne ==> motivation maximale, à condition que ce soit réel, et de bon niveau,
sinon, la réponse de *Croises* peut être incluse dans une lettre de motivation.

Comment: C’est aussi possible à dire « Passioné par les nouvelles technologies, avec lesquelles j’aime bien experimenter » ?

Comment: Ce qui est amusant, c'est que professionnellement parlant, ces phrases n'ont pas exactement le même sens. Il faudrait presque savoir de quelles technologies, et de quelles expérimentations il est question, pour quel emploi. C'est la seule solution pour arriver à la phrase juste.

Comment: @IeriOggiDomani Oui, c'est correct (à condition de continuer la phrase). Exemple : "Passionné par les nouvelles technologies avec lesquelles j'aime bien expérimenter, j'ai créé une interface pour réchauffer une tasse à distance." ^^

Answer (score 5):

Il me semble que dans un style professionnel, on ne l'indiquerait pas. Pour utiliser seulement:

> J'aime bien expérimenter les nouvelles technologies.

Answer (score 5):

Vous pourriez aussi reformuler différemment, pour glisser cette information afin d'en servir une autre. Aussi, il vaudrait peut-être mieux éviter de vous placer au centre en commençant par "je" (l'employeur cherche qu'un tourné vers l'emploi qu'il propose, par sur lui-même).

Exemples :

> Mon attrait pour les nouvelles technologies m'a permis de ...
>
> Les nouvelles technologies, que j'ai découvertes avec Arduino en 2010, m'ont orienté vers l'apprentissage du C++...

Answer (score 2):

> L'expérimentation de nouvelles technologies est l'un de mes loisirs.

Answer (score 1):

Des remarques :

1. Il y a une semi-erreur grammaticale: « expérimenter avec ». *Expérimenter* est transitif, il faut donc utiliser un COD: *expérimenter les nouvelles technologies*.
2. Lourdeur : « je suis quelqu'un qui » n'apporte rien
3. La tournure « qui aime bien » est moyennement professionnelle. Elle ressemble plus à un hobby qu'à une compétence.

En gardant exactement le sens de la phrase initiale:

> J'aime bien expérimenter les nouvelles technologies.

En simplifiant au maximum et en donnant un cachet professionnel :

> J'expérimente les nouvelles technologies.

ou (moins omniscient)

> J'expérimente de nouvelles technologies.

Comment: Les propositions de la fin n'ont pas du tout le même sens que la phrase initiale. Elles font passer l'experimentation pour une activité professionelle. Expérimenter (voir les exemples du [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exp%C3%A9rimenter)) peut aussi être utilisé sans objet, et il me parait normal de considerer les les nouvelles technologies comme un outil, pas nécessairement comme l'object d'intérêt lui même.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez oui et merci. Je modifie ça. Un CV étant fait pour enjoliver ...